# Vandermonde matrix: if c is a solution to $Vx = 0$, then the coefficients $c_1, c_2, \dots, c_n$ must all be zero

Tags: linear-algebra

Here is my problem:

> Given a vector **x** $\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, the $(n + 1) \times (n + 1)$ matrix $V$ defined by
>
> $$v_{ij} = 
>   \begin{cases}
>   1 & \text{if } j = 1 \\
>   x_i^{j - 1} & \text{for } j = 2, \dots, n + 1
>   \end{cases}$$
>
> is called the Vandermonde matrix.
>
> Suppose that $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{n+1}$ are all distinct.  Show that if **c** is a solution to $V$ **x** = **0**, then the coefficients $c_1, c_2, \dots, c_{n+1}$ must all be zero, and hence $V$ must be nonsingular.

Each entry of $V$ **c** is an $n$th degree polynomial, so if $c_1, c_2, \dots, c_{n+1}$ were not all zero, then $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{n+1}$ would have to be the roots of the polynomial.  But it's perfectly possible for an $n$th degree polynomial to have $n$ roots, so I'm not sure how I can get this to work.

Comment: There are $n+1$ $x_i$s and BTW $(n+1)$ $c_j$s (typo?).

Comment: If you will write out the matrix explicitly on paper rather than in LaTeX, you might see that the entries of $Vc$ are the values of a polynomial $c_0+c_1x + c_2x^2 + \cdots + c_nx^n$ at $n+1$ different points $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{n+1}$.

Comment: Yeah, you're right.  There are $n+1$ elements in **c**

Comment: @Dilip: What if $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{n+1}$ are the roots of this polynomial?  Then that doesn't prove anything.

Comment: @MattGregory: It does prove everything :). Since the polynomial is of degree $n$, it can't have $n+1$ zeros $x_1, \ldots, x_{n+1}$ besides it is the zero polynomial.

Comment: @martini:  Oh you're right hehe.  I was confused by the typo.

Comment: @MattGregory You should write your own answer or edit the question then, I think :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

1. The determinant of $V$ is given by
   $ \operatorname{det}(V) =\, \color{red}{??}$
2. If $x_i$'s are all distinct, then what can you say about $(x_i - x_j)$ and $\operatorname{det}(V)$?
3. If $det(A) \neq 0$ then ${\rm nullity}(A) =\, \color{red}{??}$, and what are the solutions to $Ax = 0$?
4. If $c^{T} = \begin{pmatrix} c_0 & c_1 & \ldots & c_n \end{pmatrix}$ then
   $$Vc = \begin{pmatrix}
   f(\color{red}{??}) \\
   f(\color{red}{??}) \\
   \vdots \\
   f(\color{red}{??}) \\
   \end{pmatrix}$$
   where $f(x) = c_0 + c_1 x + \ldots + c_{n} x^n.$
5. If ${\rm deg}(f(x)) = n,$ then how many *distinct* points does it take to *uniquely* interpolate $f(x)$?